# Add a <a href> in message content in Cookie Consent

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookieconsent

I am using [`cookieconsent`](https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent) by `insites`.

In the `message` part I want to write something like this:

`message: Cookies help us deliver our services. You can check <a href="#" target="_blank">here</a> our privacy policy`

Here the point is to have the  code present! See below snippet.

But this above does not work with the a `href`, how to do it? I know I can add the link at the end with below code, but that is not my objective.

```
window.cookieconsent_options = {
  message: 'Cookies help us deliver our services. You can check here our privacy policy.',
  link: 'LINK',
  target: '_blank'
};
```

Comment: @Richar Szakacs - why you change my `message`? The point is that I add the `a href></a> code in the `message` part for the config. Like this you destroy the whole question!

Comment: Please, display your desired message **as a blockquote in this case**, not as code (using `>`, that turns your message yellow) or if you want to display **as code**, rephrase your question, that you want that message as it is, as `HTML`. That way, it would be more clear, what's your intention.